# Ember {{control}} handlebars helper in outlet stops working when switching outlet model

Tags: ember.js

I have the following route map:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("data", {path: "data/:data_id"});
});
```

My application model has a tree-like structure as follows:

```
[
  {
    id:0,
    text:"John",
    children:[
      {
        id:2,
        text:"Max"
      },
      {
        id:4,
        text:"Mireille",
        children: [
          {
            id:5,
            text:"Michael"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:1,
    text:"Alex",
    children: [
      {
        id:3,
        text:"Laetitia"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want in my application template to display the main "parents" of my tree (depth zero) as a list (so John and Alex here). When clicking on John or Alex, we are transitioned to a new route named "data" passing "this" as model. In the data route, I want to display the rest of the tree: so if I clicked on John, I want the data template to show me a nested list of all his children. Since the depth of the tree is indefinite, I use the experimental handlebars {{control}} helper to generate the nested lists recursively.

It works fine when I click on either John or Alex. But then when I want to switch to the other one (so change the model passed to the "data" route by clicking on the other name), then I get weird message errors. First I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookupFactory' of undefined
```

Then if I keep trying to click I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

Example app exhibiting this problem can be found in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwOVOSO/4/edit?html,js,console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by user615276, the control helper has been removed from the Ember codebase. I solved the problem by just using views. See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oTaPECI/1/watch?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

Likely not the answer your looking for but, it appears you are using the control helper, which was experimental, not part of the public api, and has since been removed from the codebase:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/86eecd7ef7cdc7d2ea6f77b3a726b293292ec55d

If you can reproduce without the control helper, I'll gladly diagnose the issue.

Comment: Any hint on how to recursively make a tree without the control helper?

Comment: I would investigate using ContainerView.

Comment: [This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oTaPECI/1/watch?html,js,output) solves it. Thanks for pointing out that the control helper had been removed.